# Create page when a new site in multisite network is created?

Tags: customization, multisite, page-template

I found this code to automatically create a page when a new site is created in the network. But I cannot figure out how to set which page template to be used when the page is created.
I have a custom page template made which I want to use on the page that is automatically created.

I found this post explaining how to automatically create a page when a new site is made. But what about page template:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/28620/143279

Comment: Is the name of the page and its slug always the same? If so you don't need a page template, the template hierarchy lets you use slugs in the filename already

Answer (score 0):

After the page is created and you have its ID, and before you restore_current_blog() you do this:

```
update_post_meta( $page_id, '_wp_page_template', 'your-template-file.php' );
```